# Find all the points of the tangent line of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I did the derivative of this function

$(x^2+y^2)^2=8(x^2−y^2)$

and it gave me $\frac{4x(4-x^2-y^2)}{4y(x^2+y^2+4)}$

but I can't find all the points of the horizontal tangent line.

Comment: Well, how did you do the (implicit) derivative?

Comment: i know that the derivative is right i can post my calcul with my computer it will be to difficult but i know that if i want to find the point i have to put the numerator = 0 but it didn't work